# Is there a lower temperature limit, below which we cannot sense a difference in temperature?

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, sensation, sensory-systems

At work I have to handle samples stored at -20 and -70 degrees Celsius, and they don't feel that different to me.

Comment: So you're handling things nearly as cold as dry ice without protection? Sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: I touched -70 accidentally, it didn't felt as cold as I had expected.

Comment: Are you referring to the difference limens in the -20oC range at normal hand temperature, or when the hand is cooled to such temperatures? One way or another, scientific studies addressing either question have probably not been carried out due to ethical considerations. Very brief touching of cold objects may be ethically OK since the skin is not under-cooled, but such experiments are for the same reason futile because they don't tell you anything.

Comment: @AliceD Normal hand temperature.

Comment: This article goes into detail about what affects thermal thresholds in human skin.  http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Thermal_touch

Comment: I always hated opening the -80 freezer, because it felt... just incredibly cold! (With protection, but obviously not to my face over the freezer.) You just touched something shortly, probably with a short area of skin contact. With larger area of contact and longer exposure you will feel the difference. Like it is the case for hot things. But as far as reflexes go, you're supposedly already letting go/getting away before you really feel the full cold/heat.